# Вопрос о константных и статических методах

Tags: c++

Сразу хочу заявить, что являюсь абсолютным новичком. Поэтому, вероятно, вопрос окажется крайне глупым.

Вообщем, если прочитать описание константных методов, то написано так: Константный метод — это метод, который гарантирует, что не будет изменять объект или вызывать неконстантные методы класса. Если это в действительность так, то почему мы можем из константного метода вызывать статический метод того же класса?

Answer (score 4):

Все просто: статический метод не может обращаться к полям класса а значит и менять их - так что вызов статического метода из константного не нарушает константности объекта

Comment: А если передать туда адрес поля класса (экземпляра)?

Comment: @avp работает как и с любой другой функцией: если требуется константный указатель, то все ок. Иначе работать не будет. Разве что через const_cast, но если что - я такого не говорил)

Comment: Ну вы же понимаете, что вызов, скажем, `memcpy()` из метода, *объявленного константным*, на самом деле с легкостью разрушит эту самую константность

Comment: @avp memcpy требует неконстантного указателя для первого параметра. Как вы из константного объекта возьмёте неконстантный указатель?